# Start tracking angular-google-analytics

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

I wish to automatically track all user actions in an angularjs application.

My app.module.js written this way:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp', [
       // ...
        'angular-google-analytics'
    ])
    .config(['AnalyticsProvider', function (AnalyticsProvider) {
           AnalyticsProvider.setAccount('UA-XXXXXXXX');
        }])
    .run(run);

run.$inject = ['stateHandler', 'translationHandler', 'Analytics'];

function run(stateHandler, translationHandler, Analytics) {
    stateHandler.initialize();
    translationHandler.initialize();        
}
})();
```

Configuration and injection are ok and at first load the tracking seems ok but subsequent actions are not tracked, what am I missing?

Comment: Is this ionic app or pure angularjs ?

Comment: @Mr.Helper pure angularjs

Comment: http://angulartics.github.io/

Hoping this link will be helpful to you.
Let me know if it is helpful.